# How to calculate the average of a column in mySQL grouped by another column in a conditional statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, average, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I need to calculate the average of one column where a second column has the same values. For example, you have

```
Col1 | Col2
a    | 2
a    | 9
b    | 6
b    | 10
```

I need to retrieve the average of Col2 grouped by Col1, so (9+2)/2 and (6+10)/2. I am able to retrieve it in its own separate query, but it's part of a condition where the average has to be greater than 7. The sample code in mySQL is

```
SELECT Col1, AVG(Col2) FROM tableName
GROUP BY Col1;

SELECT Col1 FROM tableName
WHERE (SELECT AVG(Col2) GROUP BY Col1) >= 7;
```

The first query correctly gives me the average of Col2 grouped by Col1, but the second query simply takes the average of the entire Col2 and returns the values that are greater than the calculated average of all columns. Why is the second query not grouping by col1, and how should I change my code to correctly group the tuples?

Comment: Read Reference Manual about HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `having` clause:

```
select col1, avg(col2) as avg_col2
from tablename
group by col1
having avg(col2) >= 7
```

MySQL supports column aliases in the `having` clause (this is an extension to the SQL standard), so you can simplify it as:

```
having avg_col2 >= 7
```

Comment: @Akina: for some reason I read this as a SQL Server question (so `1.0` works around integer division). I changed the code for MySQL Thanks!